# How to automatically show a text field after selecting a specific value in p:selectOneMenu using PrimeFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I want to show a new text field, or undisable it, when I select a specific item in p:selectOneMenu.

Code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="especie" value="#{histopatologiaMB.histopatologia.especie}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Canino" itemValue="Canino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Caprino" itemValue="Caprino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Coelho" itemValue="Coelho" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Felino" itemValue="Felino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suíno" itemValue="Suíno" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Equino" itemValue="Equino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ovino" itemValue="Ovino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ave Doméstica" itemValue="Ave Doméstica" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Silvestre" itemValue="Silvestre" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

After the user selects the item "Silvestre", the following inputMask or inputText should appear:

```
<p:inputMask id="detalhe" size="30" value="#{histopatologiaMB.histopatologia.silvestreDetalhe}" maxlength="255"/>
```

I've been searching for a solution and I've found some, but none resolved my issue. If someone knows how solve it, please help me.

Comment: I did what you suggest, Lamq. Inside the listener(), I put this code: "if (histopatologia.getEspecie().equalsIgnoreCase("Silvestre")) { renderedInputMask = true; }". But this dind't work until I changed the update inside the p:ajax from "detalhe" to ":form:test" and I put the inputMask inside a <h:panelGroup id="test">.
It works, but the inputMask field is generated outside the main form, and not beside the the p:selectOneMenu.
Have you any idea how to make the inputMask field be shown next to selecOneMenu?

Comment: Yeah but for this i need your full xhtml page could you please update your post with it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is working for me.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="especie" value="#{histopatologiaMB.histopatologia.especie}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Canino" itemValue="Canino" />
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Caprino" itemValue="Caprino" />

  <p:ajax update=":formId:detalhe" listener="#{bean.ajaxMethod}"  />
```

```
<p:inputText id="detalhe" size="30" value="#{histopatologiaMB.histopatologia.silvestreDetalhe}" maxlength="255" style="display: #{userBean.showText ? '' : 'none'}"> 




private Boolean showText = false;  

//Getter-setter of showText

public void ajaxMethod() {
    if (getEspecie().isEmpty()) {
        setShowText(false);
    } else {
        setShowText(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener inside your selectOneMenu.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="especie" value="#{histopatologiaMB.histopatologia.especie}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Canino" itemValue="Canino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Caprino" itemValue="Caprino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Coelho" itemValue="Coelho" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Felino" itemValue="Felino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suíno" itemValue="Suíno" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Equino" itemValue="Equino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ovino" itemValue="Ovino" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ave Doméstica" itemValue="Ave Doméstica" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Silvestre" itemValue="Silvestre" />
    <p:ajax update="detalhe" event="change" listener="#{bean.listener}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And inside your bean add a boolean value with getter and setter.

```
public private renderedInputMask = false;


public boolean isRenderedInputMask() {
    return renderedInputMask;
}

public void setRenderedInputMask(boolean renderedInputMask) {
    this.renderedInputMask = renderedInputMask;
}
```

Inside your listener you have to do the work you need for showing or not the inputMask. When you need to show it pass the boolean value to true.

```
public void listener() {
    //Do some stuff for showing or not the inputMask.
    renderedInputMask = true;
}
```

And add the rendered attribut to your inputMask with the boolean value.

```
<h:panelGrid id="detalhe" columns="1">
    <p:inputMask size="30" rendered="#{bean.renderedInputMask}" value="#{histopatologiaMB.histopatologia.silvestreDetalhe}" maxlength="255"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: You must put the `p:inputMask` into a wrapper that will have the `id="detalhe"`